# Calculate subtotals and totals from a form with many decimal values

Tags: c#, winforms

I've got 17 currency fields on a form and need to do some calculations with their values. I wrote this method some time ago and have come back to try and refactor it to make it more efficient and/or more readable. Could I have some pointers please?

Note: The variables appended with `d` are the decimals used to hold the field values, their counterparts without the `d` are the fields themselves. I am aware that variables could do with renaming to make more sense. Hopefully it's fairly clear what this is doing by looking at the comments.

```
private void getTotals() {

    //declarations of decimal variables
    decimal curPurc1d; decimal curPurc2d; decimal curPurc3d; decimal curPurc4d; //purItemxCost
    decimal curItem1Totd; decimal curItem2Totd; decimal curItem3Totd; decimal curItem4Totd; //curItemxTot
    decimal LessItem1Costd; decimal LessItem2Costd; decimal LessItem3Costd; decimal LessItem4Costd; decimal LessItem5Costd; //LessItemxCost
    decimal ditem1Cost = 0; decimal ditem2Cost = 0; decimal ditem3Cost = 0; decimal ditem4Cost = 0; //Full cost of items

    //Check if we have some valid numbers, stop if we don't
    if (   !decimal.TryParse(curPurc1.Value.ToString(), out curPurc1d)
        || !decimal.TryParse(curPurc2.Value.ToString(), out curPurc2d)
        || !decimal.TryParse(curPurc3.Value.ToString(), out curPurc3d)
        || !decimal.TryParse(curPurc4.Value.ToString(), out curPurc4d)
        || !decimal.TryParse(curItem1Tot.Value.ToString(), out curItem1Totd)
        || !decimal.TryParse(curItem2Tot.Value.ToString(), out curItem2Totd)
        || !decimal.TryParse(curItem3Tot.Value.ToString(), out curItem3Totd)
        || !decimal.TryParse(curItem4Tot.Value.ToString(), out curItem4Totd)
        || !decimal.TryParse(LessItem1Cost.Value.ToString(), out LessItem1Costd)
        || !decimal.TryParse(LessItem2Cost.Value.ToString(), out LessItem2Costd)
        || !decimal.TryParse(LessItem3Cost.Value.ToString(), out LessItem3Costd)
        || !decimal.TryParse(LessItem4Cost.Value.ToString(), out LessItem4Costd)
        || !decimal.TryParse(LessItem5Cost.Value.ToString(), out LessItem5Costd)            
        )
        return;

        //For each of the 4 'items', try to get the value as a decimal, but only if the related checkbox is checked.
        if (Item1RateYN.Checked) 
        {
            decimal.TryParse(curItem1Cost.Value.ToString(), out ditem1Cost);
        }
        if (Item2RateYN.Checked) 
        {
            decimal.TryParse(curItem2Cost.Value.ToString(), out ditem2Cost);
        }
        if (Item3RateYN.Checked) 
        {
            decimal.TryParse(curItem3Cost.Value.ToString(), out ditem3Cost);
        }
        if (Item4RateYN.Checked) 
        {
            decimal.TryParse(curItem4Cost.Value.ToString(), out ditem3Cost);
        }

    //Add up some values which are always part of the subtotal and then the ditemx ones, which will be 0 or set to a numerical value depending if the checkbox is checked
    decimal subtotals = curPurc1d + curPurc2d + curPurc3d + curPurc4d + curItem1Totd + curItem2Totd + curItem3Totd + curItem4Totd 
                      + ditem1Cost + ditem2Cost + ditem3Cost + ditem4Cost;
    subtotal.Value = subtotals;

    //Get total minus the cost of the property (curPurc1d)
    costPlusSubTotal.Value = subtotals - curPurc1d;

    //add up all the "less" items to know how much to reduce by 
    decimal lessTotals = LessItem1Costd + LessItem2Costd + LessItem3Costd + LessItem4Costd + LessItem5Costd;
    totalLess.Value = lessTotals;

    //Total Balance due
    //subtotal minus the 'less' values total
    decimal total = (subtotals - lessTotals);
    //set the final figure into the relevant field
    balanceDueTot.Value = total;    
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Two words: loops and arrays.

There a bunch of variable names that differ only by a number. Whenever you see code like this, you can probably clean it up by creating a collection of those things and looping over them. Basically, you have a checkbox and text field repeated multiple times, and one field where you display the total of all checked fields.

1. Create a user control to encapsulate the checkbox and text field
2. Make sure this user control has a public property `decimal TotalCost { get }` that will:

   - Return the decimal-parsed values of `total - cost` for the fields when checked, and zero when unchecked.
   - Throws an exception if the decimal cannot be parsed
3. Expose a boolean property `bool IsValid` that returns true when the user as entered a valid decimals
4. Expose a public property `bool IsChecked` that returns whether or not the checkbox is checked
5. Create a collection of these user controls, one for each checkbox/text field combo on screen

Now loop and process:

```
decimal purchaseTotal = 0m;
decimal totalAmount = 0m;

foreach (var control in PurchasedItems.Where(p => p.IsChecked && p.IsValid))
{
    purchaseTotal += control.TotalCost;
}
```

I left some details out, but your code isn't really clear on what the UI looks like, or what the business use case is, but it really just boils down to:

- Create an abstraction for what each combo of controls represents (e.g. create a new user control)
- Create a collection of these controls
- Loop and calculate

Comment: Do not throw an exception if the entry cannot be parsed. Exceptions should be reserved for "continued processing is not possible" conditions. And exceptions are relatively process intensive operations. A failed parse is easily captured w/o exceptions and it's obvious what to do with it, tell the user to re-enter. This is normal run of the mill user entry error handling, do not use exceptions in these cases.

Comment: @radarbob: That's what the `IsValid` property is for. Check it before calling the TotalCost getter.

Comment: Besides, if you don't check `IsValid` first, and call `TotalCost` and it cannot parse the input, then "continued processing is not possible" and an exception is appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the fields have definitions like the following

```
public class TextboxControl
{
    public object Value { get; set; }
}

public class CheckboxControl
{
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}
```

I would create some extensions for them in order to reduce code duplication and increase readability, and pretty much this is the core idea.

```
public static class ControlsExtensions
{
    public static bool HasValue(this TextboxControl source) 
            => decimal.TryParse(source.Value.ToString(), out _);

    public static decimal GetValue(this TextboxControl source) 
            => decimal.Parse(source.Value.ToString());

    public static decimal GetOptionalValue(this TextboxControl source, CheckboxControl checkbox) 
    {
        if (checkbox.Checked)
        {
            decimal value = decimal.TryParse(source.Value.ToString(), out value) ? value : 0;
            return value;
        }
        return default(decimal);
    }
}
```

Then my next step in refactoring would to use these extensions and rearrange a bit the lines to increase cohesion

```
private void getTotals()
{
  //Check if we have some valid numbers, stop if we don't
    if (   !curPurc1.HasValue()
        || !curPurc2.HasValue()
        || !curPurc3.HasValue()
        || !curPurc4.HasValue()
        || !curItem1Tot.HasValue()
        || !curItem2Tot.HasValue()
        || !curItem3Tot.HasValue()
        || !curItem4Tot.HasValue()
        || !LessItem1Cost.HasValue()
        || !LessItem2Cost.HasValue()
        || !LessItem3Cost.HasValue()
        || !LessItem4Cost.HasValue()
        || !LessItem5Cost.HasValue()           
        )
        return;

    //Add up some values which are always part of the subtotal and then the ditemx ones, which will be 0 or set to a numerical value depending if the checkbox is checked
    decimal subtotals = curPurc1.GetValue() + curPurc2.GetValue() + curPurc3.GetValue() 
                      + curPurc4.GetValue() + curItem1Tot.GetValue() + curItem2Tot.GetValue() 
                      + curItem3Tot.GetValue() + curItem4Tot.GetValue() 
                      + Item1RateYN.GetOptionalValue() + Item2RateYN.GetOptionalValue() + Item3RateYN.GetOptionalValue() + Item4RateYN.GetOptionalValue();

    //Get total minus the cost of the property (curPurc1d)
    decimal plusSubTotal = subtotals - curPurc1.GetValue();


    //add up all the "less" items to know how much to reduce by 
    decimal lessTotals = LessItem1Cost.GetValue() + LessItem2Cost.GetValue() + LessItem3Cost.GetValue() + LessItem4Cost.GetValue() + LessItem5Cost.GetValue();

    //Total Balance due
    //subtotal minus the 'less' values total
    decimal total = (subtotals - lessTotals);

    //update the relevant UI field
    costPlusSubTotal.Value = plusSubTotal;
    subtotal.Value = subtotals;
    balanceDueTot.Value = total;
    totalLess.Value = lessTotals;
}
```

Then to make the code more C#-like, I would

- use `var` instead of `decimal`
- rename `getTotals` to `GetTotals`
- use`_camelCase` for private fileds (so `Less` becomes `_less`)
- reduce redundant parenthesis from `(subtotals - lessTotals)`
- use brackets `{}` for the `return` statement

Notice that I also grouped the update of the UI at the end of the method.

I would have some comments also for the name of the method itself as `GetTotals` implies that the method returns something, but the return signature is `void`. One idea is to use something like `CalculateTotals`.